# date/time data comes up as factor?

Tags: r, date, posixct

I'm trying to analyze some temperature logger data, but R won't recognize my date column as a date. It reads it as a factor.

```
> head(df)
        date_time     temp    site   serial
1 2020-07-16 0:00 5.938889 502trib 20292603
2 2020-07-16 0:30 5.894444 502trib 20292603
3 2020-07-16 1:00 5.822222 502trib 20292603
4 2020-07-16 1:30 5.744444 502trib 20292603
5 2020-07-16 2:00 5.705556 502trib 20292603
6 2020-07-16 2:30 5.650000 502trib 20292603

> class(df$date_time)
[1] "factor"
```

I have combed through the excel files, sorting the data by date_time, oldest to newest, to ensure that there aren't any non-date values. I managed to change it to POSIXct format with

```
> date<-as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.factor(df$date_time)),origin="2020-07-16 0:00")
```

but why did it come up as a factor in the first place?

EDIT

I exported the combined dataframe as a csv so I could inspect it. Turns out that R inserted about 3000 rows of blank data in the middle of the dataframe. From left to right, it read "         ", "NA", "           ", "NA". It was also giving me an extra level in the site column (contained a blank), but not in the serial column (contained NA). Why would it do that?

Comment: Hi! With the information currently present in your question it is hard to figure out what is going on. Can you share the original data (or a subset of it) and the code you used to read in the data?

Comment: Hi @haptic, your error is occouring probably because your hour has only one digit. Try to insert a zero and use the function `ymd_hm(df$date_time)` from `lubridate` package.

Comment: In base R: `as.POSIXct(df$date_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",  tz="EST")`